# Via Python, get local time adjusted for DST, when system clock is UTC? Must use time module not datetime

Tags: python-3.x

Via Python, get local time adjusted for DST, when system clock is UTC? Must use time module not datetime.

Using time.localtime() for returns UTC not local time.  So how do you use time module in python to get DST adjusted local time when system clock is UTC?

Comment: "Must use time module not datetime." Why? This is such an arbitrary restriction. When you have a condition that blocks the most natural solution, your chances of getting a satisfactory answer will rise considerably if you explain the reason for such a condition.

Comment: I am working on a microcontroller where memory and resources are very tight.  Limited number of modules can be present in memory, since time module core to other aspects of the solution, wanted avoid loading datetime as well.  Using datetime would be easier.  Not sure I completely agree, that I need to explain this, the question states the requirements... why that requirement exists should not matter.  Either someone has a solution or does not given the question as stated.  Suggesting using datetime... does not answer the question as asked, IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume by "system time is in UTC" you mean "the environment is not configured to use a time zone". You can set the time zone manually from Python. (`bash` example)

```
import os
import time

os.environ['TZ'] = 'Asia/Tokyo'
time.tzset()
print(time.localtime())
# => time.struct_time(tm_year=2021, tm_mon=7, tm_mday=16, tm_hour=9, tm_min=42, tm_sec=58, tm_wday=4, tm_yday=197, tm_isdst=0)

os.environ['TZ'] = 'US/Alaska'
time.tzset()
print(time.localtime())
# => time.struct_time(tm_year=2021, tm_mon=7, tm_mday=15, tm_hour=16, tm_min=42, tm_sec=58, tm_wday=3, tm_yday=196, tm_isdst=1)
```

If your environment is limited, you may not have the timezone info files at `/usr/share/zoneinfo`. You can either copy the files you will need (e.g. `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Tokyo`), or you may define your `TZ` manually. See [`time.tzset()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.tzset) for more details.

Obviously, you can also set the `TZ` environment variable before you start your program, in which case importing `os` will not be necessary:

```
TZ=Asia/Tokyo python ....
TZ=US/Alaska python ....
```

or

```
export TZ=Asia/Tokyo
python ...

export TZ=US/Alaska
python ...
```

Comment: Fortunately, the time zone is not an issue in that we get that from the user setup configuration sequence.  One of the hardware design ideas is to add GPS query support, so we could let the device find its location.  But for now, user input.  Thanks!  Great answer.